# Blockchain and Raspberry Pi

Tags: cluster

I'm bit new to this technology called blockchain. I'm trying to make a small prototype on blockchain for some learning purpose. After reading few related contents I found it requires a distributed computer system (Cluster) and also found that its even possible using raspberry pi boards.

So, can any one please educate me by giving some information like how many rasberrie's I need and what kind of OS I should install on them to run blockchain applications.

It would be very helpful to know if I get information like

- **How to do?**
- ***Any page link***
- *Is it okay to do a prototype in raspberry pi or not?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you used a search engine with the title of your question as the search parameters - there's all you'll ever need to know e.g. `how many rasberrie's I need` the answer is, (may surprise you) **ONE** ... because you do NOT a cluster at all

Comment: I've left an answer here that I hope explains why your question lacks focus.  You need to narrow your goal down.  Also, it would be more appreciated if you showed the products of your own research in the context of asking a more specific question than if you just ask, "Where should I start?".  **Note that blockchaining questions are off-topic here** and belong either on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or the [Bitcoin exchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/), which I believe actually welcomes questions about any cryptocurrency.

Answer (score 2):

> I found it requires a distributed computer system (Cluster)...

I think you've misunderstood something, although it depends a bit on how strictly you want to define your terms -- if you want to define "cluster" as a formal structure depending on specialized software above and beyond any task performed by the cluster (which is usually what is mean if you go look at stuff about "raspberry pi clusters"), this is not something required for blockchaining.  "Distributed" in that sense is more along the lines of a distributed database, which is not really considered clustering -- although it does depend on specialized software, that (database) software is there for performing the specific task all nodes are participating in: Providing a distributed database.

Another formal property of clusters is that each node is essentially interchangeable and all of them are equally capable of, and arbitrarily engage in, performing the same set of tasks.  Although this might apply in a restricted sense to nodes in a blockchain network, a cluster would be considered *a single node* in such a network, and not the network itself.

A node in a blockchain network runs independently of the other nodes in the sense that if you are the adminstrator of such a node, you do not have to have any special access to any of the other nodes -- they are run by other people.  That is *not* how clustering works, or at least, clustering [in the sense I think you will find described online with regard to the Pi.](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3156748/computers/10-amazing-raspberry-pi-clusters.html)

The point is, while you could use such a cluster as a blockchain node, it is not required.  **You can use a single computer including a single pi** (just keep in mind it won't accomplish much compared to non-educationally motivated nodes -- but then neither will a cluster of pis).

So, you have perhaps taken an interest in two distinct things, blockchaining and clustering.  *Do not try to pursue them together*.  That is a bad way to learn.  Pick one or the other and focus on that.

The Raspberry Pi is probably more suitable to studying clustering, since you can buy multiples of them cheaply.  For blockchaining, you might as well work on whatever normal (almost certainly much beefier and easy to use) computer you have available.